# Ubuntu 18.04 python-tz and python-zmq errors

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, python-2.7

I've got a side install of Python 2.7.15rc1 and I've created some problem when I changed the python symlink to Python3 temporarily and changed back.

Now when I try to from updates via apt.

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

This is what I'm getting.

---

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-zmq
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-tz python-zmq
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
94 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/642 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 632636 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-tz_2019.2-1ppa1~bionic_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python-tz package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-tz_2019.2-1ppa1~bionic_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python-tz package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-tz package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python-zmq_18.1.0-1ppa1~bionic_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-zmq.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-zmq.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python-zmq package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-zmq_18.1.0-1ppa1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python-zmq package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-zmq.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-zmq.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-zmq package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-tz_2019.2-1ppa1~bionic_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-zmq_18.1.0-1ppa1~bionic_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output shows this error:

> pycompile: not found

`pycompile` is provided by **minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)** ie. `python-minimal` or more precisely `libpython2.7-minimal`

Please read [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pycompile.1.html).

---

To fix it you need to reinstall `libpython2.7-minimal` or `python-minimal` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7-minimal
```

Or:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.    So trying:  ` sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7-minimal`   resulted in   ` $ sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7-minimal
....
E: Internal Error, No file name for libpython2.7-minimal:amd64`   However, substituting python-minimal resolved the problem. **Thank you**.

Comment: @guudr You are most welcome.